# Python Keyboard.Write getting slower over time

Tags: python, keyboard

Im a python noob, so sorry in advance.

I am trying to make an application that does a specific repetetive task for me in a video game in the game's console. This is my code:

```
import time
counter = 1
time.sleep(5)
for counter in range(9999):
    s=str(counter)
    z=str(0)
    keyboard.press_and_release("0")
    if z in s:
        keyboard.write("assimilate ")
        if counter > 999:
            a=4
        elif counter > 99:
            a=3
        elif counter > 9:
            a=2
        else:
            a=1
        for j in range(a):
            if s[j] == 0:
                keyboard.press_and_release("0")
                keyboard.press_and_release("0")
            else:
                keyboard.press_and_release(s[j])
    else:
        keyboard.write("assimilate ", counter)
    keyboard.press_and_release("enter")
```

The task would be to start by pressing 0 to open the console. Then writing "assimilate " and then a number increasing in every big for loop. (most of the code is about pressing 0 two times if the number its supposed to type has a 0 in it, because 0 also closes the console), but what im getting is this:

0assimilate 0
0assimilate
0assimilate

This gets slower every loop (3rd time it takes 3s to write a single letter), but only for the "keyboard.write("assimilate ") part.

Btw what its supposed to write is this:
0assimilate 1
0assimilate 2
0assimilate 3
0assimilate 4
0assimilate 5
0assimilate 6
0assimilate 7
0assimilate 8
0assimilate 9
0assimilate 10(double press on 0, because pressing 0 closes the console, but keeps the text written into it, and one of the zeros will actually appear in the input field)
0assimilate 11
...
0assimilate 9999

Comment: I didn't understand what the code should do if the number has a 0 on it. For example 103, what should do? the follwing?: "0assimilate 1003enter0assimilate 1004"? Could you expand your last example until 11 please?

Comment: @AlexMontano Did it, yes by the way, thats what its supposed to do.